# Angularjs routing to # causing problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fairly new to angularjs, trying to make a single page application.
The default page to load should be a home page, and I also want a home button to route to this page.

Nav bar in HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">

...

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

...

<div ng-view></div>
```

in app.module.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'main',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'about',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
            controller: 'contact',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
});

app.controller('main', main);
app.controller('about', about);
app.controller('contact', contact);

function main() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = "Home page";
}

function about() { //stuff }

function contact() { //stuff }
```

When the page loads, everything displays correctly, and the url is `http://localhost:8007/#/`

My problem is that when I click Home, the url becomes `http://localhost:8007/#` and nothing displays. About and Contact both work as intended.

I know I can just change my Home button to have `href="#/"` but that feels like I am targeting the symptoms, not the problem. I feel like I really shouldn't have to do that.

I have tried adding `.when('', {` to app.module.js, but this does nothing.

Comment: I'd use an `otherwise` route to handle the home view. This has the benefit of handling routes if the user edits the URL. `#asdf` would still be handled by the `otherwise` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home href will be `<a href="#/">Home</a>` which then translates to the path `"/"` you defined in `$routeProvider`.

Dont use `href="#"` anywhere in the app

Comment: `otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})`  .. the angular paths are everything after `#` or `#!` if you use hashbang for SEO

Comment: but you can't use `#` as href anywhere

Comment: ok... you got me there...have never tried it and just did. The router rejected the change and stayed on current path

Comment: ok..i was able to replicate that by pasting url into another tab. Never thought of this before actually. Could probably catch it in `$routeChangeError`  https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve-routechangeerror ... my guess is the path will be empty string

Comment: would put that into `angular.module('app').run()` not in a controller

Comment: actually it looks like it throws an error in console when only `#` is present

Comment: likely would yes but it really seems like an edge case. Might also be able to catch it in `$routeChangeStart` event, not sure if that would fire before the error or not